# Value of variable changes

Tags: c++

In the code below, I am trying to store the value of array at index 0 in the temp variable. In this line of code: `a[i-1]=a[i]-a[i-1];` when i=0, a[i-1] becomes a[-1].

1. Why is compiler not giving any error?
2. Why does the value of temp variable is affected and becomes zero after the first iteration, though it is assigned a value only when i=0 and temp is not used anywhere else?

For example, when I gave input as:

```
3 1 2 3
```

Output:

```
i:0
a[0]: 1
TEMP: 1
TEMP: 0
TEMP: 0

TEMP: 0
```

What's actually happening? Please explain with reference to the working of compiler. I know that if I put a condition `if(i!=0) a[i-1]=a[i]-a[i-1];` the code will work normally. But I want to know why is this happening with the given scenario.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[10],i,n,temp;
    cin>>n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>a[i];
        if(i==0){
            temp=a[i];
            cout<<"i: "<<i<<endl;
            cout<<"a[0]: "<<a[i]<<endl;
        }
        cout<<"TEMP: "<<temp<<endl;
        a[i-1]=a[i]-a[i-1];
    }
    cout<<endl<<"TEMP: "<<temp;
}
```

Comment: [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)

Comment: a[i-1] is out of bounds at first iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Why is compiler not giving any error?

The compiler is not required to give any error. Accessing array out of bounds has undefined behaviour. It might seem obvious that the array is going to be accessed out of bounds at run time (then again, perhaps not so obvious since the author of the program didn't catch it before running the program), but it would be prohibitively expensive for the compiler to check execution paths in search for bugs in general.

> 2. Why does the value of temp variable is affected and becomes zero after the first iteration, though it is assigned a value only when i=0 and temp is not used anywhere else?

Because the behaviour of the program is undefined.

---

It is usually pointless to analyze why program behaves in some way, when it is allowed to behave in any possible way. However, this case it seems that most likely: When you write out of bounds, you overwrite some memory that isn't part of the array. Other variables may be located in the memory that isn't part of the array. Therefore overwriting some memory that isn't part of the array may corrupt the value of some other variable. That is what you observed.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Why is compiler not giving any error?

As @user2079303 already mentioned, such error is too difficult for compiler to find. There're separate tools for finding such more complicated errors - static and dynamic code analyzers. For example, if you use default static code analyzer from VS 2015, it gives the following warnings:

```
Severity    Code    Description
Warning C4701   potentially uninitialized local variable 'temp' used
Warning C6385   Reading invalid data from 'a':  the readable size is '40' bytes, but '-4' bytes may be read.
Warning C6386   Buffer overrun while writing to 'a':  the writable size is '40' bytes, but '-4' bytes might be written.
Warning C6001   Using uninitialized memory 'temp'.
```

If you want extra safety for your projects, consider enabling all (or almost all) available warnings and run code analysis regularly.